# Best tag suggestion for Fantastic World of DC Collins

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a question on the main site [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47018/are-the-similar-1984-movies-the-fantastic-world-of-d-c-collins-and-cloak-and), asking "Are the movies 'The Fantastic World of D.C. Collins' and 'Cloak and Dagger' connected somehow?"

I created [cloak-and-dagger](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloak-and-dagger) for the latter film, which is fine.

The former film is too long for a tag. I've created [fan-world-dc-collins](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan-world-dc-collins) which is extremely clunky, but I'm not sure what else this could reasonably be reduced to.

What are people's thoughts on the best tag for this?

Answer (score 3):

Its very tricky for sure but i don't find [the-fantastic-world](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-fantastic-world) or  [fan-world-dc-collins](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan-world-dc-collins) much applicable. As the first one seems too generic and the second one being inaccurate.

I think we should go for [fantastic-world-of-dc-c](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-world-of-dc-c). Might sound bit clumsy but maybe less confusing.

Comment: I think the benefit of this is that as someone starts typing "fantastic-world" it will be obvious. Richard is *of course* right, this is a very minor thing and quite possibly we'll never get another question like it again. But it would be good to know what to do in future, with tags that are too long. Do we make the whole thing more concise, or do what you've done and keep the *start* as is (to help people looking for tag) but make the end much shorter.

Comment: @AndrewMartin When someone type "fantastic-world", then `the-fantasic-world` will pop up, too, though.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that [fan-world-dc-collins](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan-world-dc-collins) sounds very odd (and I wonder why you didn't at least put in the "of", which would have had room). And given that tags are usually typed in consecutively from the beginning, the shortening from "fantasic" to "fan" might be rather **detrimental for actually finding the tag** by typing it in.

A rather simple solution might be to just use the first part and make it **[the-fantastic-world](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-fantastic-world)**. This might on the other hand sound a bit too generic, but I still think it's a better choice than the current solution. And as long as noone shows me a more relevant *The Fantastic World* that it could be confused with, I'd say it's sufficiently clear for now.

Comment: Given the odds of anyone ever asking another question about this low-budget 80s children's film, it wouldn't really matter what tag gets used. I vote for TFWDCC

Comment: Sounds good for now. There are a bunch of fantastic world films, but none have questions asked against them (and looking at them, none look like they'll have any questions asked against them any time soon).

Comment: @Richard Which doesn't mean we shouldn't strive for a sensible tag name, though. And no, no effing acronyms, please! ;-P

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Drastically overthinking minutiae is what SE does best.

Comment: @Richard I'm not overthinking it. I would actually just have changed it if I hadn't seen the meta question. But since there is one, I thought about it for 2 minutes and took another 5 minutes to write an answer (and another 3 for some comments). I'd not call that "overthinking" really. A "don't care" attitude doesn't lead to a particularly reasonable tagging system at all. Do you propose we simply ingore this meta question or what is it you're actually arguing *for* here?

Comment: What about [tag:fantastic-world-of-dc-c] ? bit clumsy for sure.

Comment: @AnkitSharma You can propose it as an answer. I don't like it that much, though. But it's a valid alternative.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson done. Now both answer have equal votes :D

Comment: @AnkitSharma: That's cause I upvoted both because I'm not too bothered. Let's be honest - the three of us are pretty much the only ones who are going to be engaged in this :) I'll let you two decide.

Comment: The only I see with having it be only the-fantastic-world is http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=the+fantastic+world&s=all

Answer (score -1):

How about just [dc-collins](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-collins)?

Comment: I can already see that getting slapped on a few Batman and Superman questions, though.

Comment: As in DC Comics?